# Multitenant/Shared Application system, how to maintain multiple tentant-specific identifiers?

Tags: ravendb, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant system where each tenant shares the same instance of the codebase, but has their own databases.

I'm using RavenDB for persistence, with a standard c# facade/BLL backend wrapped with Asp.net WebAPI, and I'm finding that at every lower level operation (deep within my business logic classes) that touch the datbase, I need to pass in an identifier so that my RavenDb client session knows which database to operate against.

When the user authenticates, I resolve the appropriate database identifer,  store it in the session manager.  Every call against the Web API layer passes in a session ID which resolves the database ID in the backend, which is then used to pass into every single facade/BLL call.

All my dependencies are handled via an IoC container at the WebAPI level, but i can't pass in the database ID at this phase because it can be different for every user that is logged in.

this, of course is getting tedious.

can someone give me some guidance as to what I can do to alleviate this?  Maybe perhaps some sort of policy injection/AOP solution?

a rough sample of my backend code looks like..

```
public class WidgetService()
{
     private WidgetBLL _widgetBLL;
     private ISessionManager _sessionManager;

     public WidgetService(WidgetBLL _widgetBLL, ISessionManager sessionManager)
     {
          _widgetBLL = widgetBLL;
          _sessionManager = sessionManager
     }

     public Widget getWidget(string sessionId, string widgetId)
     {
          string DbId = sessionManager.ResolveDbId(sessionId)
          return _widgetBLL.GetWidget(string dbId, string widgetId);
     }
}



public class WidgetManager()
{
    public GetWidget(string dbId, string widgetId)
    {
          using (IDocumentSession session = documentStore.OpenSession(dbId) 
          {
             var widget = session.load<Widget>(widgetid);
          }
          return widget;
    }
}
```

the DBID is the identifier for that particular tenant that this particular user is a member of.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change how you are using the session.
Instead of opening and closing the session yourself, do that in the IoC code.
Then you pass a session that is already opened for the right db.